# MVC4 Razor Storing Html in Database and rendering in view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently storing Html markup in an NVARCHAR(max) Sql Server DB column. Using @Html.Raw(model.VariableName) to successfully render Html in view.

The problem arises when the html string includes the @char ie.

### @String.format("{0}", VariableName)

or @Html.LabelFor() and @Html.TextboxFor. Rather than telling the view engine to execute the associated code, it renders each statement as a string ie. "

### @String.format("{0}", VariableName)

".

Looking for a way to include the @ char in a stored Html string so the Razor engine can parse the code and execute.

Comment: So you are not storing Html. You are storing Razor.

Comment: Correct. The Html that I am storing and returning works great, the razor code returns as an Html string and renders in text.